# CoffeeScript: capture first word in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I have an input field with the `id` `post_date`.

The value entered in this field is a date: it can vary, of course, but it **always** uses the same structure:

```
Monday, November 30 2015 05:55 PM
Tuesday, December 01 2016 05:55 AM
Wednesday, December 02 2015 05:55 PM
```

I need to capture the day in this date, ie: the first word of the string.

How can I do that with CoffeeScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is always a comma, use it to split and get first value :

```
date = "Monday, November 30 2015 05:55 PM"
alert(date.split(",")[0])
```

if all dates are in the same string, first split with "\n" then take each string to get day with ","

Answer (score 1):

you can just split by **,** and get the first element

```
    var value = 'Monday, November 30 2015 05:55 PM'
    value.split(',')[0]
```

The syntax of coffee is the same as vanilla js here